# Symfony 3.4.9 many-to-many relation not saved in DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I'm developing a crowfunding website and I have two entities: User and Campaign
One user can be two things: team and funder

for now I have:

```
class Campaign
{
public function __construct() {
    $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

 /**
 * Many Groups have Many Users.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="teams")
 */
private $team;

/**
* @param Team $team
*/
public function setTeam(User $team)
{
    $this->team[] = $teams;
}
public function getTeam()
{
    return $this->team;
}
}
```

The problem is that the teams are not saved in the DB (all the other info on the form are saved normaly). Would you help me understand what I did wrong please ?

Thank you

Comment: Check this example http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: Thank you Liora but I already found this example and I'm having a hard time with the setter. Perhaps it's not the way to do it and that I should create a campaign-team/campaign-funder entity first ?

Comment: You're missing a lot of annotations that are on the example, that's why your table is not created

Comment: Please add the code in the controller and also the User entity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your method setTeam ? You give $team in parameter but in your assignation of the array $this->team you only use $teams with an s and no the $team which is in param.

```
/**
* @param Team $team
*/
public function setTeam(User $team)
{
    $this->team[] = $teams;
}
```